# Renault Scenic II 1.9 dci, model 2004 facing start problem!

Tags: electrical, starting, renault, scenic

My car is a Renault Scenic II 1.9 dci (Diesel) ... the car was working fine and everything was good except one small problem (it was small) ... the problem was the left headlight (rear one) stopped working. So i took it to a friend and wanted to change & check that lamp ... we discovered the "lamp" itself was working fine but we suspected something (error & prob) in the fuse-box. We checked all fuses, they were all fine & only one relay in the fuse board seemed to be slightly disconnected (underneath).

NOTE: **Of course this needs to disconnect the battery first and disconnecting all the wire cables of fuse-box.**

So we welded that one and rechecked all the fuse-box board diagram and relays & fuses (with voltmeter)... everything was fine...Then we reconnected the fuse-box cables and the battery... (up to here everything seams typical)... we checked the headlight (left one) it becomes OK and worked fine.

The Problem:
when I insert the key-card to start the engine.... it doesn't start... and the first message was "electronic fault" then this message gone and it keeps saying "steering not locked \ steering locked" with no power to start the car.

What I tried to do were:

1. Recheck all fuses and relays in the fuse-box and others inside the car "under steering" (there are all fine)
2. Cleaned the fuse-box & cables & slots with a special spray for (for electronic boards)
3. Checked the (DF002 DEF1) (the small box under the steering that responsible for locking and unlocking the steer, electronically) ... it was blocked & stuck ... so I fixed it...

[image]

Things that are not checked:

1. If there is (are) other relays outside the fuse-box that responsible for AC & power (not checked) I don't know where they are!! & how to check them
2. battery cables (positive) & fuses (it has three fuses) they are working fine but needs to be cleaned... they seem to be corroded... I don't know if this makes any different!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would like to inform you that the issue has been solved....the problem was caused by the wires in the grey plug (plz see attached picture) which responsible for feeding the electronic board with electric & power... we this plug has been resolved... then, the error message "steering locked & Not locked" disappeared & the car start just normal now... thanks anyway for giving me a chance to share my experience with you.

Regards[image]